# Polymer 1.0 Auto binding template with iron-ajax

Tags: ajax, data-binding, polymer-1.0

I am trying to request a service via iron-ajax using the following in my index.html:

```
<body class="fullbleed">
    <template is="dom-bind" id="mainTemplate">
        <paper-material class="todo" elevation="1">
            <span>Mohammed</span>
        </paper-material>
        <br/>
        <iron-ajax id="requestGeoname" auto url="http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON" params='{{input}}' handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
        <span>{{data.geonames.0.countryName}}</span>
        <br/>
        <span>{{data.geonames.0.name}}</span>
    </template>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
```

In my JS code, I would like to read {{data}} but could not do it. I tried to do it using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
...
console.log(document.querySelector('#requestGeoname').data);
...
</script>
```

The code gives me undefined when I log {{data}}.

Comment: Try adjusting this to `console.log(document.querySelector('#requestGeoname').lastResponse);`. The name `data` that you have bound to is only relevant in the parent scope. When you're accessing the data on the iron-ajax element directly, you have to use `.lastResponse` because that is what that property is named in the iron-ajax element's context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
...
var template = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('template[is=dom-bind]');
console.log(template.data);
...
</script>
```

As Dogs pointed out, the `data` property doesn't belong to `requestGeoname`-element, it belongs to the "template" item that is binded with `dom-bind`. Dogs solution should also work, but if you have other variables to use in your application, this is probably the better solution since they are now accesible through the `template`-object. For example:

```
...
template.myOthervariable = "derpherp";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the request is finished. It's better to use the event `response` (More info: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#response).

```
<script>
document.getElementById('requestGeoname').addEventListener('response', function(event){
    console.log(event.detail.response)
});
</script>
```

or declaratively:

```
<script>
var mainTemplate = document.getElementById('mainTemplate');
mainTemplate.onPlacesResponse = function(event){
    console.log(event.detail.response);
};
</script>

<iron-ajax … on-response="onPlacesResponse"
```

Comment: That works too, but I wanted to access {{data}}. Thank you.